# How to perform with CheckBox and RadioButton in RibbonControl in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, checkbox, devexpress, radio-group, ribbon-control

How to work with CheckEdit in RibbonControl ? I drag a CheckEdit and place it in the RibbonPage. But Is show like Button how to change it to normal "CheckBox" ??

I used RadioGroup and perform through SelectedIndexChanged, I hide caption now it shows only RadioButtons only. But I need Caption to particular RadioButton not common to RadioGroup. I add 3 RadioButtons so I need to show 3 caption near/ under to particular RadioButton.

How to complete my task ? Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Ribbon Designer to assign a CheckEdit to your RibbonPage.
[image]

This will shown as a normal CheckEdit.
To Add a description to your RadioGroup you have to Add RadioGroupItems via

```
radiogroup.edit.items
```

Property. Each item can hold a description and a value. The description will be displayed in Ribbon if the RibbonPage is big enough to show the descriptions! Further information here:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRadioGrouptopic

Comment: Hi Sebi, thanks for answering. If i choose that Checkedit,  CheckedChanged Event is not available in that item. How can i write my code ?

Comment: @Sri Hari i just found a dirty way so far. You can you repositoryItemCheckEdit to handle CheckChanged event. Then you can use baredititem1.EditValue to become the value. Declare the EditValue as bool in the designer and cast it in your code. Let me know if you need example.